# Is a large tumor is more likely to develop hypoxic regions?

Tags: human-biology, cancer, blood-circulation

It is known that cancerous tumors in humans can develop [hypoxic regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoxia_(medical)) where no blood nor oxygen arrive to some volume of its cells, creating a dead lump inside or around the tumor.
See [Wikipedia - Tumor hypoxia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumor_hypoxia).

> - Are hypoxic regions and regions without blood supply are more common in large tumors than in small tumors?
> - What is the likelyhood or frequency of hypoxic regions in small (< 2 cm) and large (> 4 cm) tumors?
> - What is the typical size of an hypoxic region within a tumor?

The [article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumor_hypoxia) is too techincal and very hard to be read and understood, and doesn't have an explicit answer to my question.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer because it's more of a model system *in vitro*, and wouldn't model in the *in vivo* microenvironment, but it's interesting to look at Table 1. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4764677/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prescence of hypoxia is independent of size, grade, or histology. It occurs due to a cut off in blood supply to the tumour. Or insufficient vasculature systems, meaning the oxygen cannot diffuse all the way into the tumour. Aberrant growth of tumours can increase the likelyhood of tumours developing hypoxic regions.

Comment: Hypoxic region can be formed in any tumor, big or small. But does large tumor have significantly larger hypoxic regions?

Comment: Not necessarily. Its all tumour dependant.

Comment: And statistically?

Comment: There is no relationship. The paper titled: "Detection and Characterization of Tumor Hypoxia Using pO2 Histography," looked at several tumor types none of which have a correlation between size and hypoxia.